# how to display tiff files in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, tiff

Can any one help me out that how to display tiff files(Contains multiple images like pdf) in ios?

```
NSData *imageData = [Base64 decode:_img];
[_wv loadData:imageData MIMEType:@"image/tiff" textEncodingName:nil baseURL:nil];
```

I am using the code above. But it is displaying only the first image in tiff file.
how to display all the images in tiff file.

Comment: this link is not solution for my question. That is different from my question.

Answer (score 1):

Just try this..

```
NSString *str = [imageData base64Encoding]; 
NSData *new_data = [NSData dataWithBase64EncodedString:str];
UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageWithData:new_data];
[image_view setImage:image2]; // Just check with image view
[web_view loadData:new_data MIMEType:@"image.tiff" textEncodingName:nil baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: Still displaying only first image in tiff file.

Comment: @Boggarapu did you check this `image2.images`(for animated images, `images` property of `UIImage` will hold all images)?

Comment: .png or .jpeg images are stored into array. and to show that array "images" property is used. But tif/tiff is containing multiple images like pdf. images property doesn't work for tiff file.

Comment: @Boggarapu Did you try this? Is it work for you? I think, it will be just store as raw data(no need to .jpeg or .png ), which point out by `images` property(array)?

Comment: its not working. it is showing a warning "Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSArray *' to parameter of type 'UIImage *' "

Comment: Hey man, I told that try this `UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageWithData:new_data]; image2.images = //check this`?

Comment: That is what I tried. I finally found the solution that ios doesn't support tiff files. try to open some sample tiff file in safari browser. It shows only the first image of file.

Comment: iOS doesn't support multi-page TIFF: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6680065